# Changing background-color depending on content text

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have a div and i want background color depending on div's context. example i type in two div class #999 and setting background color to #999. how can i do it with pure javascript?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test").textContent;
$(".test").attr({
"style" : "background-color: + x + ;"
});
}
```

```css
.test{
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#555;
  color:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">#999</div>
```

Comment: Question is not clear what do you mean by `example i type in two div class`

Comment: I know a jQuery solution if you don't mind using that?

Comment: Please explain more, you mean when the text inside the div changes the color should change too?

Comment: @brk sorry for my bad English i mean that i want in example when i type in <div class="test">color code here</div> background color change to color code.

Comment: @Martin okay, i want check this out.

Comment: @novruzrhmv since you wanted pure JS, you should look at @ Banujan Balendrakumar's answer.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi  i mean that i want in example when i type in <div class="test">color code here</div> .test class's background color change to color code.

Comment: The method `getElementsByClassName` returns HTMLCollection which is sort of an array. To make your code work change it into this: `document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want to do in vanilla JS, no jQuery needed.

```js
function changeColor(element) {
  // Get the text content of the provided element.
  const
    color = element.textContent;
  // Update the element's background color. 
  element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get all the elements from the DOM with the test CSS class. You can also
// use the getElementsByClassName if you prefer.
const
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
// Iterate over all the element and for each element call the changeColor method.
elements.forEach(changeColor);
```

```css
.test{
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#555;
  color:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">#999</div>
<div class="test">#f00</div>
```

Comment: very very thanks. it's working correctly. but i use this way [link](https://codepen.io/novruzrhmv/pen/wEpqmM) what is my fault?

Comment: You never declare the elements variable, there is nothing to loop over.

Comment: I've forked your pen and added my answer, this works just fine. See here: https://codepen.io/tbusser/pen/eLyVeb. Is there something else you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i have one more question; how i can use this context in cssText example:
 `document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].style.cssText = "background: color;";`

Comment: Assuming `color` is some variable you have declared, you can do the following: `document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].style.cssText = "background: " + color + ";";.`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
    function setColour(e) {
        
        e.style.backgroundColor = e.innerHTML;
        
    }
</script>

<style>
    .test{
      padding:5px;
      background-color:#555;
      color:white;
      display:inline-block;
      min-width:100px;
      border:1px sloid black;
    }
</style>

    Type the colour code or name inside the div:<br><br>
    <div class="test" onkeyUp='setColour(this)' contenteditable>#999</div>
```

Comment: you can type colour name too :)

Comment: i know this method but i want take color in html not typeable

Comment: Want colour picker?

Comment: What do u mean by `want take color in html `

Comment: simply when i change html text also change background color same.

Comment: such example `var x = $(".test").text();` it gets div's text which have test class. and i use this text in background color.

Comment: $(".test").css('background-color',x);

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/novruzrhmv/pen/wEpqmM) here it's not working still background color not #999